# MySQL Performance: Many tables or many rows?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I want to log access to pages in my PHP/MySQL  app to implement a view count similar to the one on SO.
My plan is to count the requests by unique IP addresses on each page. There about **5000** different pages with a view-count.
(I know counting IPs is not exact but that is OK for my purposes.)

I see two options to do organize the database tables:

- Either one  large table with the fields “page_id”, “request_ip”. Assuming each page has 50 views by unique IPs on average, I'd get **5000 x 50 =  250 000 rows**. As the views are displayed on the pages, the table will have read and write access for each request on each page.
- The other option is to have one table per page with a single column “request_ip”. I'd then have **5000 tables storing 50** rows on average. A table will only get accessed when it's page is viewed.

Which one is better generally and performance wise? Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: I don't know what's the best choice concerning performance but I think that surely the second option in terms of cleaness is very ugly.

Comment: how busy is the website at peak time? like 10 requests per second or more ?

Comment: It's below 10 requests per second at the moment. But it should scale well in any case

Comment: is 50 views by unique ips per day? per hour?

Comment: It's just a rough estimate of how many overall views each page will have on average and that should still scale well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

5000 tables means 5000 different queries + 5000 different sets of index + 5000 different sets of data competing for space in the server's caches. Performance will most likely be abysmal.

Multiple tables storing exactly the same data structure is almost ALWAYS a bad design. If you're worried about performance, you can use MySQL's [partitioning support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) to split the table into multiple pieces automatically, and that's done transparently to the end-user (eg. your queries).

Comment: Not necessarily, how about huge data that google stores. they would have same data structure but many tables. So it depends on task at hand. In this case, it would agree that its a bad idea. MySql Partioning is something that you need.

Comment: That's comparing a whale to an amoeba. Google has MapReduce and BigTables and GFS. They're not directly comparable to a bog-standard MySQL install.

Comment: agreed. but "same data structure is almost ALWAYS a bad design" is misleading in general context.

Comment: @RaviBhatt, I disagree you need to look at the 95%, not at the remaining 5% or less. And Marc did say **almost always**  +1

Comment: @Johan amazing to see those number. do you have any source? I thought people are heavily using haddop, hive. mongodb etc etc. So a general statement "almost Always" is misleading. What would you say about systems that do heavy data processing and they do have diff tables with same structures. Search for several analytics companies online. Facebook, Twitter, StackOverflow,Google and many others will have that. Now all of above can not be just 5%.

Comment: further, mysql partions will be created on a key. in this case page_id, so mysql will end up creating 5000 separate indexes anyways. So the argument that the server needs to manage 5000 diff indexes is again not valid.

Comment: The layout for stackoverflow is public, see: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new **(on the right side)** and there's no duplicate table in sight. **That's what partitions are for**  It is my belief that you have no idea what you are talking about. Besides there are 100's of millions of websites and you just mentioned 4.

Comment: i am sure you know that they store in that format! You seem to know too much. thanks for the enlightment!

Answer (score 2):

Wouldnt a better a approach to be to have a table that stores DateTime of access, page id, ip address etc etc.  Then every time a page is access you simply add a row to the table.  That will give you the data at a raw level and then you can simply aggregate it to answer the questions that you want.

Storing the data in this way also allows you to answer more granular questions like how many page views were made on a particular day or week?  Which you wouldn't be able to do with the table structure you have purposed in your question.

Comment: The problem is, I'd have a lot of rows (each pageview over a long period of time) and I have to compute the amount of views for each page request. Now I know from experience that making a query on very large tables (+1 000 000 rows) is a performance problem. So while your solution is great for tracking purposes where there is mainly write access to the table, it is not an option in my case.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a datawarehouse database solution and not mySql then.  Have you looked into something like infoBright?